# Need to optimize scraping code - select URL with parameters

Tags: python, web-scraping, optimization

This is a simple code for get url with search parameters. It actually works, but I think it needs to be optimized.

```
def target_url(search_term, include_term, intext_term, target_site_in, page):
    
    base_template_0 = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}+"{include_term}"+intext:{intext_term}+site:{target_site_in}&hl=en&rlz='
    base_template_1 = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}+"{include_term}"+intext:{intext_term}&hl=en&rlz='
    base_template_2 = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}+"{include_term}"&hl=en&rlz='
    base_template_3 = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_term}&hl=en&rlz='

    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')

    base_url_0 = base_template_0.format(search_term)
    base_url_1 = base_template_1.format(search_term)
    base_url_2 = base_template_2.format(search_term)
    base_url_3 = base_template_3.format(search_term)

    url_template_0 = base_url_0 + '&start={}'
    url_template_1 = base_url_1 + '&start={}'
    url_template_2 = base_url_2 + '&start={}'
    url_template_3 = base_url_3 + '&start={}'

    if page == 0 and search_term and include_term and intext_term and target_site:
        return base_url_0
    if page == 0 and search_term and include_term and intext_term:
        return base_url_1
    if page == 0 and search_term and include_term:
        return base_url_2
    if page == 0 and search_term:
        return base_url_3
    else:
        if search_term and include_term and intext_term and target_site:
            return url_template_0.format(page)
        if search_term and include_term and intext_term:
            return url_template_1.format(page)
        if search_term and include_term:
            return url_template_2.format(page)
        if search_term:
            return url_template_3.format(page)
```

Four parameters are required: search_term, inclusion_term, input_term, target_site_in - In each case, a conditioned URL was specified differently.

Give me a better idea for optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having multiple templates strings and selecting on them, you can make a method that gives you the final search query:

```py
def get_search_query(search_term, include_term, intext_term, target_site_in):
  response = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
  if include_term:
    response = f"{response}+{include_term}"
  if intext_term:
    response = f"{response}+intext:{intext_term}"
  if target_site_in:
    response = f"{response}+site:{target_site_in}"
  return response
```

now in your method you can call it

```py
def target_url(search_term, include_term, intext_term, target_site_in, page):
  query = get_search_query(search_term, include_term, intext_term, target_site_in)
  url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&hl=en&rlz='
  if page != 0:
    url = f"{url}&page={page}"
  return url
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You've made my poor code great.I'll really use it well.Thanks once again.